Azure Function App - frequent hang and deadlocks
I am writing a Azure Function App with Python SDK that has multiple Timer Triggers. Each of those timer triggers pull all users or groups from Microsoft Entra ID with a help of msgraph api and writes them to a Postgres DB also hosted on Azure. As I briefly described in title, my Function App gets frequent hang and deadlock errors displayed in "Resource & Health" tab (every 2-3 days once). We are on EP1 App Service Plan.
Here is a short code example of the failing Trigger:

PostgreSQLConnector where I connect to my Postgres DB and insert:

class PostgreSQLConnector:
        def __init__(self):
            self.host = os.getenv("PG_HOST")
            self.dbname = os.getenv("PG_DB")
            self.user = os.getenv("PG_USER")
            self.password = os.getenv("PG_PASS")
            self.sslmode = "require"
    
       def __enter__(self):
            self.connect()
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            return self

       def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
            self.cursor.close()
            self.close_connection()
    
    def insert_many_into_table(self, table_name, columns, entries):
        sql_query = f"""
        INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join([''.join(name) for name, _ in columns])})
        VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(columns))})
        """
        try:
            batch_size = 10000
            batches = [entries[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(entries), batch_size)]
            commit_interval = 10
            execute_many_counts = 0
            batch_counter = 0
            for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
                self.cursor.executemany(sql_query, batch)
                batch_counter += len(batch)
                execute_many_counts += 1
                if execute_many_counts % commit_interval == 0:
                    self.connection.commit()
            self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            self.connection.rollback()
            raise Exception(f"Error committing changes: {e}")


A msgraph api class instance where I authenticate and pull all users from Entra:

class GraphHelper:
    client_credential: ClientSecretCredential
    app_client: GraphServiceClient

    def __init__(self, tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
        client_id = client_id
        tenant_id = tenant_id
        client_secret = client_secret
        self.client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            tenant_id, client_id, client_secret
        )
        self.app_client = GraphServiceClient(self.client_credential)

    async def get_all_entra_users(self):
        request_configuration = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters=UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
                select=self.default_user_select_properties,
                top=999
            )
        )
        all_users = []
        top_users = await self.app_client.users.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        for user in top_users.value:
            all_users.append(user)
        next_link = top_users.odata_next_link
        try:
            while next_link:
                top_users = await self.app_client.users.with_url(next_link).get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
                for user in top_users.value:
                    all_users.append(user)
                next_link = top_users.odata_next_link
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(e)
        return all_users


function_app.py trigger definition, pulling users from msgraph and writing them to PostgresDB

tenant_id = os.getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID")
client_id = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET")

graph_helper_instance = GraphHelper(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

@app.function_name(name="allEntraUsersTimerTrigger")
@app.timer_trigger(schedule="0 0 1 * * *", arg_name="allEntraUsersTimerTrigger", run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=False)
async def all_entra_users_timer_trigger(allEntraUsersTimerTrigger: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    try:
        users = await graph_helper_instance.get_all_entra_users()
        user_entries = [tuple([getattr(user, key) for key, _ in SchemaDefinitions.columns_users]) for user in users]
        with PostgreSQLConnector() as postgres_helper_instance:
            postgres_helper_instance.drop_table(SchemaDefinitions.table_name_users)
            postgres_helper_instance.create_table(SchemaDefinitions.table_name_users, SchemaDefinitions.columns_users)
            postgres_helper_instance.insert_many_into_table(SchemaDefinitions.table_name_users, SchemaDefinitions.columns_users, user_entries)
    except Exception as e:
        # Error handling

There is around 50k users that I need to pull and write to DB so this quallifies as heavy I/O function I would assume. Running this locally works without problem. Manually triggering it by sending POST request on deployed function app also works without problem. The only problem is that it frequently hangs when it triggers. Is there something fundamentally wrong how I have setup my code that could cause that hangs and deadlocks when it automatically triggers? Could it be that Postgres writes are not async? Does anyone have an idea?
If you need any more information please let me know

Is the storage account associated with the Function app shared amoung other function apps as well? See shared storage accounts and Avoiding host ID collisions

@RuiJarimba I was told that yes, they use same storage account for multiple function but that I should not worry about it since it is correctly configured. I will try to override host ID as explained in the article you linked!

I had some issues with a shared storage account a few years ago which were solved by overriding the host ID. If this is indeed your problem please let me know and I'll post my comment as an answer.

would that be an option to use asyncpg and its pool? that way you would always maintain a connection, as the hangging might be due to new connections?

@RuiJarimba Hello, after around two weeks it failed again. I assume there is some other problem in my code that is causing the issue or the host is not setup correctly.

The original implementation i.e. calling urls with msgraph with_url in loop was causing the memory usage to hit Azure Function host memory usage limit of 1.5GB:
await self.app_client.users.with_url(next_link).get(request_configuration=request_configuration)

I replaced the above implementation with the following async function:
import aiohttp

async def async_fetch(self, initial_url, expand_value=None, get_only_top=False, top=999, headers=None, consistent=False):
    token = self.get_access_token()
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    if consistent:
        headers["ConsistencyLevel"] = "eventual"
    result_list = []
    next_url = initial_url
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        while next_url:
            async with client.get(next_url, headers=headers) as response:
                response_json = await response.json()
                single_result = response_json.get('value', [])
                result_list.extend(single_result)
                next_url = response_json.get('@odata.nextLink')
    return result_list

This function is triggered with:
initial_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top={top}&$select=id,deletedDateTime,accountEnabled,businessPhones,city"
users = await self.async_fetch(initial_url)

In addition to that, I am calling a clear memory function to speed up memory release:
def clear_memory(function, locals):
    for var in list(locals.keys()):
        del var
    logging.info(f'{function}: memory cleared')

This approach helps manage memory usage more effectively, preventing the Azure Function host from stopping the execution due to high memory consumption.
Here is an image from metrics that shows the before and after
memory usage

I agree with @Rui Jarimba and @Je Je, You can consider using separate Storage Accounts for each if your Function apps to avoid deadlock and asyncg package to avoid I/O blocking and deadlocks. Refer the code below:-
import asyncpg
import os

class PostgreSQLConnector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = "valleypostgresql76.postgres.database.azure.com"
        self.dbname = "postgres"
        self.user = "xxxxxx"
        self.password = "xxxxxx"
        self.sslmode = "require"
        self.pool = None
    
    async def initialize_pool(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            database=self.dbname,
            host=self.host,
            ssl=self.sslmode
        )

    async def __aenter__(self):
        if self.pool is None:
            await self.initialize_pool()
        self.connection = await self.pool.acquire()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        await self.pool.release(self.connection)
    
    async def create_table(self, table_name, columns):
        column_defs = ', '.join([f"{name} {type}" for name, type in columns])
        create_table_query = f"""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} (
            {column_defs}
        )
        """
        await self.connection.execute(create_table_query)

    async def insert_many_into_table(self, table_name, columns, entries):
        sql_query = f"""
        INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join([''.join(name) for name, _ in columns])})
        VALUES ({', '.join(['$' + str(i+1) for i in range(len(columns))])})
        """
        try:
            batch_size = 10000
            batches = [entries[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(entries), batch_size)]
            commit_interval = 10
            execute_many_counts = 0
            for i, batch in enumerate(batches):
                await self.connection.executemany(sql_query, batch)
                execute_many_counts += 1
                if execute_many_counts % commit_interval == 0:
                    await self.connection.execute('COMMIT')
            await self.connection.execute('COMMIT')
        except Exception as e:
            await self.connection.execute('ROLLBACK')
            raise Exception(f"Error committing changes: {e}")

# Example usage
async def main():
    table_name = "users"
    columns = [
        ("id", "SERIAL PRIMARY KEY"),
        ("name", "VARCHAR(100)"),
        ("email", "VARCHAR(100)"),
        ("created_at", "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    ]

    async with PostgreSQLConnector() as postgres:
        await postgres.create_table(table_name, columns)

# Run the example
import asyncio
asyncio.run(main())


Also, You can fetch the 50K users in Batch to improve its concurrency:-
import logging
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphServiceClient
from msgraph.generated.users.users_request_builder import UsersRequestBuilder

class GraphHelper:
    def __init__(self, tenant_id, client_id, client_secret):
        self.client_credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
        self.app_client = GraphServiceClient(self.client_credential)

    async def get_all_entra_users(self):
        request_configuration = UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters=UsersRequestBuilder.UsersRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
                select=self.default_user_select_properties,
                top=999
            )
        )
        all_users = []
        top_users = await self.app_client.users.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        for user in top_users.value:
            all_users.append(user)
        next_link = top_users.odata_next_link
        try:
            while next_link:
                top_users = await self.app_client.users.with_url(next_link).get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
                for user in top_users.value:
                    all_users.append(user)
                next_link = top_users.odata_next_link
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error fetching users: {e}")
        return all_users

Additionally you can add maxConcurrentRequests to improve your Azure Functions performance.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "maxConcurrentRequests": 100,
      "maxOutstandingRequests": 200
    }
  }
}

Even diagnose and solve problems will give you more insight in your Functions behaviour:-

You can also monitor the Function by referring my SO answer1. Also, you can check my SO answer2 to avoid deadlock issue.

Hello, thank you for your reply! I am aware of diagnose and solve problems but it is not giving any errors unless hang or deadlock happens and it causes incomplete timer trigger execution. I will try to set maxConcurrentRequests as you said. Regarding postgres in the meantime we switched to mssql but the problem persists

@AleksandarVuckovic Yes, Also try to fetch the users as batch and then write them to your postgresql or mssql

@NaveenSharma This solution did not solve my problem. I will write the solution that solved my problem in a couple of days of course.
